# Simple php image changer with xml data

Tags: php, xml, image

Here I am using this code with an xml file.

I would like to display more images not just one -> for example: slideshow, or a simple "image rotator/changer". How can I do this?

PHP:

```
<?php

                if ($this->aktuelles) {
                    $id = 1;
                    foreach ($this->aktuelles as $aktuelle) {
                        if ($aktuelle->url == '') {$url = '';}
                        else {$url = $aktuelle->url; $target = 'target="_blank"'; $btn = '<a href="' . $aktuelle->url . '" class="read-more btn" target="_blank">' . 'weiter lesen</a>';}
                        //$text = substr($aktuelle->text, 0, 1150) . ' ...';
                        $text = $aktuelle->text;
                        echo '
                            <article class="clearfix">

                                <a class="linkimage" href="images/aktuelles/' . $aktuelle->image . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/aktuelles/' . $aktuelle->image . '" alt="' . $aktuelle->title . '"/></a>
                                <h4 class="title"><a href="' . $url . '" ' . $target . '">' . $aktuelle->title . '</a></h4>
                                <p>' . $text . '</p>
                                ' . $btn . '
                            </article>
                            <hr>
                        ';
                        $id++;
                    }
                    unset($id);
                }
                elseif ($this->aktuelle) {
                    $aktuelle = $this->aktuelle;
                    $title = $aktuelle->title;
                    $url = SITE_PATH . $aktuelle->url;
                    $text = $aktuelle->text;
                    $image = $aktuelle->image;
                    echo '
                        <a href="'.SITE_PATH.'/'.$this->lang.'/aktuelles" class="read-more btn">&#171; Zurück</a><br><br>
                        <article class="clearfix">
                            <a class="linkimage" href="images/aktuelles/' . $image . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/aktuelles/' . $image . '" alt="' . $title . '"/></a>
                            <h4 class="title"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></h4>
                            <p>' . $text . '</p>
                        </article>
                    ';
                    unset($aktuelle);
                }
            ?>
```

Here is the xml code what i wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aktuelles>
    <aktuelle>
        <title><![CDATA[THIS IS THE TITLE]]></title>
        <image>image1.jpg</image>
        <text>
            <![CDATA[
            This is the content<br>
        </text>
        <url></url>
    </aktuelle>
</aktuelles>
```

Comment: Your xml contains only image though?

Comment: Not just image, There are the title and the content text.